# how to write a C++ debug function in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

I want to write a windows debug function like linux one:

```c
#define debug(fmt, ...)  printf("[%s:%d]"fmt"\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: thats what you want, but what is the question? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: That should work. If you're having problems, create a [mcve]. If you don't know whether you have a problem, try it before assuming that you do.

Comment: Ask yourself first "why do I need debug traces in my code?". I've found over the years I could get rid of almost all debug traces and logging (except on incoming API calls to see what users are doing), just by writing unit tests and testing code first before integrating it.

Comment: Use Trace Points in Visual Studio for temporary debug output. For permanent tracing output use ETW. It's been around for two decades now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for string concatenation like that to work, you need spaces between the strings.
So this part:

```cpp
"[%s:%d]"fmt"\n"
```

changes to

```cpp
"[%s:%d]" fmt "\n"
```

Otherwise, `fmt` is assumed to be a string literal operator (`operator""fmt`), which you don't want here.

Don't forget to include `<cstdio>` for `printf`, and then it should work as expected.